# What determines whether a URL ending in.py will show as the script itself or a page generated by the script?

Tags: python, html, url, browser, webserver

A browser displays [this](http://old.zderadicka.eu/mailexp.py) link as the script itself.
[This](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/controllers/api.py) link, on the other hand, returns a web page ostensibly generated by the script.

What determines whether a browser will show the script? How does the browser know not to to directly display the raw Python code (and nothing else) in the GitHub URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first link simply links to the file on the server - the second link is to a git server which when asked for the file gets the latest, *or specified*, version of that file and presents a web page with the line numbers, syntax highlighting, ect.

So the answer to your question is that the **web server** and its software, settings, etc., determines what is presented for any given link.

Notice that in the case of the second link you can use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reddit/reddit/master/r2/r2/controllers/api.py to get the actual script displayed.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the same goes for a .php or .asp file, right?

Comment: The same goes for just about any content - even to an extent `.html` - if the servers been configured to show *possibly some* `.htlm` files as source, or syntax highlighted source, that is what you will get.